# How to handle non-typescript project requesting @types installation for project dependency?

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, create-react-app, c3.js

I've set up a project using `create-react-app` with `custom-react-scripts` so that I can use decorators for `MobX`. My goal is to use the `react-c3js` library for data visualization. *Everything works*, but my IDE (VSCode) is showing me this warning when I try to import from `react-c3js`:

> [ts]
>   Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-c3js'. '/Users/banana/code/d3/d3-gdp/node_modules/react-c3js/react-c3js.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
>     Try `npm install @types/react-c3js` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'react-c3js';`
>   module "/Users/banana/code/d3/d3-gdp/node_modules/react-c3js/react-c3js"

Since my project doesn't use typescript I imagine I'm not sure why I'm seeing this error.

Here's my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "d3-gdp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "custom-react-scripts": "0.2.2",
    "d3": "^5.7.0",
    "mobx": "^5.5.0",
    "mobx-react": "^5.2.8",
    "npm": "^6.4.1",
    "react": "^16.5.2",
    "react-c3js": "^0.1.20",
    "react-dom": "^16.5.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-dashboard": "^2.0.0"
  }
}
```

This is the file where I import react-c3js and use the example from their documentation. I've put a comment by the line that the IDE complains about:

```
// src/index.js

import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import registerServiceWorker from "./registerServiceWorker";
import C3Chart from "react-c3js"; // IDE COMPLAINS HERE
import "c3/c3.css";

const data = {
  columns: [
    ["data1", 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
    ["data2", 50, 20, 10, 40, 15, 25]
  ]
};

ReactDOM.render(<C3Chart data={data} />, document.getElementById("root"));

registerServiceWorker();
```

Is that warning an issue with the `react-c3js` module or my project? Is this a case of "if it isn't broken don't fix it"? **My goal is to understand the origin of this warning and if it's something I should be concerned about.** Thanks for any insight!

Comment: Does my answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

In your workspace settings, set `javascript.validate.enable` to `false`. This will disable TypeScript checking on any JS file within that workspace.